# drupal_goto ignored in custom form submit handler

Tags: forms, users, redirection

I'm working on a site at the moment where some nodes are hidden behind a login. You can see a list of them, but to view them you need to sign in.

The sign in is done by showing the user login block in a lightbox.

Now the problem I'm having is the submit handler for the form isn't working properly. In my template.php file, it looks like this:

```
function fisita_redirect_after_login(&$form, &$form_state) {
   drupal_set_message($form['hidden_paper_url']['#value']);
   drupal_goto("http://www.google.com");
   //$form['#redirect'] = $form['hidden_paper_url']['#value'];
   //$form_state['#redirect'] = $form['hidden_paper_url']['#value'];
}
```

The Drupal set message, works fine, and it is outputting what I want (the URL we're trying to redirect to), but any attempt at changing the page isn't running. Either redirect or drupal_goto.

Does anyone have any clues?

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to customize the destination that a user is redirected to after logging in ?

Comment: Yeah, clicking on a node link, changes the value of "hidden_paper_url" to the node's url, so after the login is successful I want the page to redirect to this url. Google's just in there as a test at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a problem like this and I used this as a workaround to get the page to redirect:

```
$url = url("node/$nid");
header("Location:$url");
drupal_set_message(t('Message to be displayed in the next page'));
drupal_exit();
```

Comment: You sir are a hero.

Comment: +1...but if you're using Drupal 7 it'd be wise to use `drupal_exit()` rather than `exit()`, so Drupal can properly clear up after itself

Answer (score 1):

I think it's `redirect` in `$form_state` not `#redirect`:

`$form_state['redirect'] = 'path/to/page';`

Answer (score 1):

Dave's answer works, but it just felt wrong, like wasn't **"the Drupal way"**...

```
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account) {  
    $GLOBALS['reasons_to_h8_drupal']='this';
}
function mymodule_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code){
    if (@$GLOBALS['reasons_to_h8_drupal']=='this'){
        $path = '/first-page-after-login';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Are you sure "fisita_redirect_after_login" is working?

2.I had met a similar problem like this, change form redirect or `druapl_goto` in form_submit not work, it maybe this function is not last change form function, because `form['#submit']` is an array.

Comment: 1. Yeah, the set message is showing up so the function's working.

Comment: so, maybe second possible status ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow point 2. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination)

> The Login Destination module allows you to customize the destination
>   that a user is redirected to after logging in, registering to the site
>   (7.x), using a one-time login link or logging out (7.x). The
>   destination can be an internal page or an external URL. It is possible
>   to specify certain conditions like referring pages or user roles and
>   make the destination depend upon them. You may use PHP snippets to
>   provide custom conditions and destinations. It is also possible to
>   keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out.

Comment: Can the destination be set to a form field?