# Login not redirecting to SSO (external) server login page

Tags: 7, users, forms

I'm trying to replace Drupal authentication with the authentication from a SSO server, in a scenario discussed [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39065/understanding-drupals-session-management-and-user-authentication). I'm trying to modify the `login_block` (on "Homepage" as well as "Access Denied" page), and `login_block_form` (at `mysite.com/user/login`). I did reset the default "Log in" button and replaced it with "SSO Log in" button, and on its `#submit`, using `drupal_goto`, I'm trying to redirect it to SSO server Login page. But, I'm still getting redirected to `mysite.com/node?destination=node`. I'm not able to figure out what the problem is. And inputs would be appreciated.

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_block' || $form_id == 'user_login') {
    // Add a button to form, used to login to SSO
        $form['foo'] = array(
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#value' => t('SSO Log in'),
            '#submit' => array('MODULE_user_login_foo_submit'),
            '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
        );
        // unset the current default login button of Drupal
        unset ($form['actions']['submit']);
  }
}

function MODULE_user_login_foo_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_goto('PATH/TO/SSO-SERVER-LOGIN-PAGE.ASPX', array('external' => TRUE));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//implements hook_form_alter()
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_block' || $form_id == 'user_login') {
    $form['#action'] = 'PATH/TO/SSO-SERVER-LOGIN-PAGE.ASPX';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unset the destination before calling drupal_goto():

```
unset($_GET['destination']);
drupal_goto('PATH/TO/SSO-SERVER-LOGIN-PAGE.ASPX', array('external' => TRUE));
```

Another option would be to code the redirection logic yourself (brought up as an answer by Dave [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33277/drupal-goto-ignored-in-custom-form-submit-handler)).

The problem exists because [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) is overriding the given path with the destination if the latter is not external (check the function code).

Additionally:

Since you are using the button type the submit handler isn't being invoked ([documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#button)). For my solution to work you would have to change the type to 'submit' or move the redirection logic into the validation handler (by changing '#submit' to '#validate').

Comment: thank you for the reply; but it didn't work :( I changed the `$form['action']` to get the required redirection

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. I forgot to mention that Drupal isn't invoking the submit handler since you're using the button type. To get my solution working you would have to change the #type value to submit or switch out #submit with #validate. Your own solution is fine as well though, just letting you know for future reference :)

Comment: I should've investigated more before going for a work-around. anyways thank you very much :)