# Prevent node from being saved

Tags: 7, nodes

So, this seems like a rather simple task but I've been stuck on it for a while.

I need either in `hook_node_presave` or in `hook_node_submit` (but NOT in `hook_node_validate`) to check for a field value in a node and according to that value choose whether or not to cancel the node saving procedure.

How do I do that? (The canceling part, not the checking part ;) )

Comment: `hook_node_validate()` is the correct hook, why can't you use it?

Comment: cause for some reason which is not relevant to the issue, the 'problematic' value has not been set yet. Dont ask me how and why, but it's the trurh =)

Comment: if it makes any difference, it's a 'hack' I want to prevent where if someone gives you a link to post content in a public og_group you are not a member of, the link looks like this: node/add/article?gids_node[]=1 and seems to set the value from NULL to 1 after the form validation. It's weird but it happens.

Comment: Took me multiple print_r's to figure it out. I am positive it happens, I am clueless to why exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)()

I believe this function obliterates any followup processing other than saving session data and forwards the user immediately on to a new page.

> Excerpt from Drupal.org: drupal_goto();
>
> This function ends the request; use it instead of a return in your
>   menu callback.

To define where the users will be sent to, simply pass the same data you would to the [url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7)() function.

For example:

```
drupal_goto('node/44');  // Sends users to yoursite.com/node/44
```

An update regarding the drupal_goto() function from a submit handler (See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/33281):

```
//Note from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/33281
//When using drupal_goto() from a submit function you may need to be more aggressive. 
$url = url("node/$nid");
header("Location:$url");
drupal_set_message(t('Message to be displayed in the next page'));
drupal_exit();
```

Comment: Was about to answer my own question. A drupal_goto() call seems to work just fine. My only "issue" now is that the redirect doesn't seem to work in case I wanted it to go to a specific page (say the front page). It breaks the node_save but leads me back to the page I started from which is not *that* bad, but I'd like to have a nice redirect option.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a functional example. :)

Comment: Did that, didn't work that's why I am puzzled.

Comment: Very interesting.  Just experienced the same thing.  It looks like this has been noted before.  See: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/33281/1747

Comment: This is probably not a great approach. It will break things like views bulk operations.

Answer (score 9):

I've found that the best way is to just thrown an error during presave. Here's a simple example:

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node){
  if(empty($node->title)){
    throw new Exception('Error saving node: Title cannot be empty');
  }
}
```

The [node_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7)() function has a try...catch block wrapping the presave step that will catch the exception.

The advantage of this over drupal_goto() is that, if you're importing multiple nodes, it will skip the current node and proceeed to the next one. This is great if you're using something like the Feeds module. In contrast drupal_goto() will exit immediately and may interfere with other steps in the request or cron, which will break importing multiple nodes.

Comment: Great solution!